# popup goes up while entering text

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a pop up with a text box and 2 buttons.

This is how i am creating

```html
<div data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" id="Name" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <center> <h3>Name</h3> </center>
        <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" data-mini="true" id="nname" value="" placeholder="Name" data-theme="c" />
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" ><img src="Image/Cancel.png" width="100px" height="40px" ></a>
        <a href="#" data-inline="true" id="exisitng" ><img src="Image/Continue.png" width="100px" height="40px" ></a>
    </div>
```

Whenever I enter data into text box the popup goes up and I can`t see what I am entering into the text box.

I tested on device 2.3.3 on the device it is causing this problem, but when I run on my simulator 4.2 i am not facing the issue.

How to avoid it?.

Thanks:)

Comment: Which version of jqm are you using?

Comment: @alkis i am using jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js

Comment: What do you mean it goes up? The keypad is appearing so it's forcing the popup to move up? Maybe the viewport is too small? Have you tried with another positioning?

Comment: Maybe it's the browser you are using. i.e android default browser is not so good. Try with another one. Also maybe you should consider moving to the 1.3.1 version. It's stable now and has major bug fixes

Comment: @alkis Ok i will check it out.